# Citing Arxiv manuscripts in IEEEtran bibtex

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style, arxiv

I would like to learn to cite arXiv documents properly in LaTeX IEEEtran style.

Biblatex has special entries for arXiv, but the standard bibtex, as well as IEEEtran Bibtex style that I am using, do not seem to provide arXiv support. How to you modify @article, or other entries, to cite an arXiv paper?

I want to also produce a url to the document webpage in the pdf file.

Comment: Bibtex "Online" entry is not supported in IEEEtran Bibtex style.

Comment: I am not sure but I would say that these new mechanisms (citing open archives for instance) were made possible only with biber/biblatex.

Comment: I thought so too. One thing I could come up with was using @unpublished entry and putting arxiv link in the "note" item. It would have been great if biblatex entries could have been directly used.

Comment: you may want to ask IEEE to upgrade their Latex source files to the biber/biblatex association. Using "note" seems to be an inefficient trick.

Answer (score 3):

I also use `note` field. For example, I put this information in the note field:

```
[arXiv preprint \href{http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0876}{arXiv:1409.0876}, September 2014]
```

And, then I use either one of the following redefinitions of `\href`:

```
\def\href#1#2{#1 #2}
```

or

```
\def\href#1#2{#2}
```

The first definition keeps the url (without any actual hyper-link), while the second one only keeps the arXiv ID:

```
[arXiv preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0876 arXiv:1409.0876, September 2014]
```

versus

```
[arXiv preprint arXiv:1409.0876, September 2014]
```